# Unable to delete multiple grid view records

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am trying to delete multiple grid view records. I tried as shown below.

```
       public void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringCollection orderNumberCollection = new StringCollection();
            if (gridOrders.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                 foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gridOrders.Rows)
                    {
                         if (gvrow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
                             CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)gvrow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkdelete");
                            Label lblOrderNumner = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("labelOrderNumber");
                            Label lastName = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("LabelLastName");
                            if (cbx.Checked && lblOrderNumner != null)
                            {
                                orderNumberCollection.Add(lblOrderNumner.Text);
                            }
                         }
                    }
            }
        if (orderNumberCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            DeleteMultipleOrders(orderNumberCollection);
        }
}
```

But always check box control showing "Checked = false". Why check box control always showing false even I checked some of the check boxes?

Here is my Grid view code:

```
    <asp:TemplateField> 
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table><tr><td ><asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" /></td><td><asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" /></td></tr></table>   
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkdelete" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderNumber") %>' Font-Bold="false" />
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Please show the GridView code

Comment: Are you reloading the GridView  even on postbacks? That would cause the checkboxes to deselect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Tim on this, it sounds like you are loading your gridview from within `Page_Load`, which is fine. but in your case you would need to make sure your gridview loading code looks like this:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //gridview loading code
}
```

this prevents your gridview from being reloaded (and losing which boxes are checked) when you click your delete button